# Creating angular Directive with custom attributes and template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm having some problems with a custom directive to display some images instead of a dropdown. but by now i'm stuck with displaying the correct html from my template function.
Writing the image path directly into my template generates attributes for every part between slashes. E.g.:

```
'src="/path/to/image.jpg"'
```

is changed to

```
src=" path"="" to="" "image.jpg"=""
```

i even tried to puth those paths in my model but this is the result: https://plnkr.co/edit/EGm5nk?p=preview

i found a working example but cannot find the difference: http://plnkr.co/edit/nQbrSi?p=info

my additional question to this: how do i address a list correctly in my directive?

EDIT: That error was so stupid and easy to oversee

Comment: You will need to post your directive code to get a meaningful response.

Comment: You just missed to close the class inside directive. updated plunk here - https://plnkr.co/edit/Q5CkuyqQGPW54qiNNCaq?p=preview

Comment: @Developer omg thanks, watching for hours on that code did me not see this. i'm feeling so stupid by now. this explains why slashes and spaces had that stupid behavior

Comment: @southzrgw - dont worry, that happens :) Sometimes all you need is just extra pair of eyes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed to close the class inside directive. Change

```
var html = '<div class="foobar">'+
'                    <div class="row"> '+
'                        <div class="col-xs-3 ng-repeat="'+ attrs.ttOptions + '"><img ng-src="{{item.path}}" /></div> '+
'                    </div> '+
'                </div>';
            return html;
```

to

`.....<div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="'+ attrs.ttOptions`.....